# Looking for a function having its fourier components

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse, fourier-transform, analytic-functions

So I have a function in Fourier :
$$ f(x)=\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^3}\sin(n\pi x)$$
Is there a method to check if it can be an "explicit" function (I mean not with series)? The closest I found is :

$$ \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^{T} x^3 \sin(n\pi x)dx=-\frac{2 (-1)^{n T} (-6 + n^2 \pi^2 T^2)}{n^3\pi^3}$$ 
if $T=1$ it's not so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^3}\sin(n\pi x)$$
$$ f''(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x)$$
$\sin(n\pi (x-1))=\sin(n\pi x)\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n\sin(n\pi x)$
$$ f''(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi (x-1))$$
With $X=x-1$ we get the Sawtooth wave or Sawtooth function $SW(X)$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html
$$\frac12-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi X)=SW(X).$$

[image]

$$f''(x)=-\frac12+SW(\pi (x-1))$$

I suppose that you can continue the double integration on the first segment which gives the repeated pattern :

[image]

This looks like a sinusoid, but it isn't a sinusoid. The pattern is an arc  of cubic curve which equation is obtained thanks to the double integration of the linear function.

Note : The Sawtooth function can be expressed on the form of a complex equation. See Eq.$(11)$ in the web-page referenced above. Theoretically the integrations allows to express $f(x)$ on closed form in terms of complex polylogarithm functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just found

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^3-x}{12}\sin(n\pi x)dx=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3\pi^3}$$

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with whether $f$ is analytic.